# multiple navigations with same tables many to many relationship entity framwwork

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've just started using EF code first, so I'm total beginner in this topic.

I working on task management system. I am working with many-to-many relationships between tasks and employees. There are three kinds of relationships

1. Task-Employee (Here employee is the person responsible for the task)
2. Task-Employee (Here employee is the person who will be notified after task completion)
3. Task-Employee (Here employee is the person who will approve the task)

I have  three table for each these many-to-many relationships.
So far I 've tried this approach, I am getting all records in collection for Responsible not the related one.  Any suggestions for approach? What I am doing wrong?

Code I'm using for getting data is

```
var tasks = db1.Tasks.Include(t => t.TaskPriority).Include(t=>t.Responsible).Where(t => t.tas_status.Equals(AppGlobals.PENDING) || t.tas_status.Equals(AppGlobals.WAITING));
```

_

```
[Table("Task")]
public class Task
{
    public Task()
    {
        this.Responsible = new HashSet<Employee>();
        this.Notified = new HashSet<Employee>();
        this.Approved = new HashSet<Employee>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int tas_id { get; set; }
    public string tas_name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Responsible { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Notified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Employee> Approved { get; set; }

}

[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    [Display(Name = "Employee ID")]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int emp_id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
    public string emp_name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Assigned { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Notified { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Approved { get; set; }
}

[Table("TaskResponsible")]
public class TaskResponsible
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Task")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int tas_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Person Responsible")]
    [Key, Column("emp_id", Order = 1)]
    public int emp_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Responsible { get; set; }

}

[Table("TaskApproval")]
public class TaskApproval
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Task")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int tas_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Person Approved")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int emp_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Approved { get; set; }
}


[Table("TaskNotified")]
public class TaskNotified
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Task")]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int tas_id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Person Notified")]
    [Key, Column("emp_id", Order = 1)]
    public int emp_id { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Notified { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Responsible)
            .WithMany(d => d.Tasks)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("tas_id");
                m.MapRightKey("emp_id");
                m.ToTable("TaskResponsible");
            });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Notified)
            .WithMany(d => d.Tasks)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("tas_id");
                m.MapRightKey("emp_id");
                m.ToTable("TaskNotified");
            });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
            .HasMany(a => a.Approved)
            .WithMany(d => d.Tasks)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapLeftKey("tas_id");
                m.MapRightKey("emp_id");
                m.ToTable("TaskApproval");
            });
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Are you mapping each many-to-many relationship to individual tables, via fluent API?

Comment: yes i ve added the code scroll down @Stoward94

Comment: just a hunch but have you tried to comment out the many-to-many classes you have made and just leave the fluent API mapping?

Comment: not yet @Stoward94

Comment: Multiple object sets per type are not supported. The object sets 'Responsible' and 'Notified' can both contain instances of type 'Polani.Models.Employee'.

Comment: @asfandahmed1what do you mean not the related one when you say "I am getting all records in collection for Responsible not the related one."

Comment: @CodingYoshi i'm getting all records not related with a particular record